# Trigger formatter in a custom plug-in in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatter

I writing my own text editor plugin for eclipse. I am now working on my own formatter. Actually, following that link http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_support_formatting_in_my_editor%3F. 
I have written my Strategy, I have overridden getContentFormatter in my SourceViewerConfiguration..

As I run my plugin and press Ctrl+Shift+F - and nothing happens.

I think that I'm missing a step here. Should I create a handler or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me. I have created a handler with the following executors body:

```
//get the editorPart    
if (editorPart != null) {
                ITextOperationTarget target = (ITextOperationTarget) editorPart
                        .getAdapter(ITextOperationTarget.class);
                if (target instanceof ISourceViewer) {
                    ISourceViewer textViewer = (ISourceViewer) target;
                    ((ITextOperationTarget) textViewer)
                            .doOperation(ISourceViewer.FORMAT);
                }
            }
```

Then just create menu items and bind them to the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be you skipped the last part of the linked page?

> Finally, you will need to create an action that invokes the formatter. No generic formatting action is defined by the text infrastructure, but it is quite easy to create one of your own. The action’s run method can simply call the following on the source viewer to invoke the formatter:

```
sourceViewer.doOperation(ISourceViewer.FORMAT);
```

Comment: What is this action? A Handler?